# httpContext.Session is always null when routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't get session when do routing HttpContext.Current.Session  is also always null

my code looks like this

```
public class LocalizedRoute : Route
{   
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {     
        if (httpContext.Session != null)
        {
            if (httpContext.Session["User"] != null)
            {
                User user = httpContext.Session["User"] as User;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Session state has not been established while routing, it is too early in the request pipeline.

You can probably get the results you want using a pre-request filter instead of doing it in the route code.

Comment: I need user in route because I want to take from user his language information and set the language